# ipython/python broken after upgrading to OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, python

After upgrading to OS X Mavericks, it seems Python broke. I get the following when I try to run `ipython`:

```
~ $ ipython 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/ipython", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

Similarly I noticed that some other packages seem to be missing, even when using the default `python` (as opposed to `ipython`):

```
~ $ python
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

`numpy` definitely worked before the upgrade. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

**Update**: Just noticed that running `sudo easy_install numpy` makes `numpy` work again. It gives the following output:

```
WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.

To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.

Password:
Searching for numpy
Best match: numpy 1.6.2
Adding numpy 1.6.2 to easy-install.pth file

Using /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
Processing dependencies for numpy
Finished processing dependencies for numpy
```

I am 100% sure I had numpy installed already when the machine was still running OS X Mountain Lion. Do I need to reinstall all of my python packages now? If so is there an easy way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS upgrades from Apple tend to wreck havoc on Python installations, usually resulting in the re-installation of whatever packages you had installed. There is no way to fix it at this point, but going forward you could consider running [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to keep your Python installs and packages separate from the OS.

A little more info can be [found here](http://www.macdrifter.com/2013/10/getting-python-ready-for-os-x-upgrades.html).

Comment: or even use a python.org or macports or homebrew python